# How can I make eclipse CDT ignore errors?

Tags: c++, eclipse, eclipse-cdt

I'm having a lot of parser errors from eclipse but I don't have these errors when I compile the code. How can I ignore them?

Comment: Another gem in the vein of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9199974/gcc-allow-undefined-symbols

Comment: For me, it had no effect to change the settings in Window | Preferences | General | Editors | Text Editors | Annotations. But if you get a lot of errors on std::things, this thread offers some tips that might eliminate those errors: https://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/t/490066/

Answer (score 5):

In the Indigo version of the CDT:

> Project Settings -> C/C++ General -> Code Analysis

You can enable/disable specific errors and warnings, as well as customize inclusion and exclusion patterns for those warnings.

If you get a large number of "Type 'TYPE' could not be resolved" errors, perhaps you need to make sure Eclipse can find all your code and libraries. You might want to check:

> C/C++ General -> Paths and Symbols

Comment: Beginning with Eclipse Oxygen.3 (or.2). warnings/markers can be suppressed by simply using "Quick Fix".

Answer (score 0):

Under Settings you can selectively turn off and on which errors it reports, and how it displays them.

Answer (score 0):

1 ]

- Windows-->preferences-->type "anno" you will find annotation
- Navigate(scroll) to warning section , uncheck vertical ruler and rest
  if you wish

---

other method

- 2] go to project explorer    right click any project you wish to
  disable/turn off warnings or such
- --->properties    ---> c/c++ settings-->tool settings--->search your compiler c or C++ and     ---> navigate to warning section----uncheck
  all (/any checked)
  ------> build project and Voila warnings gone :)